# non identifying relationship in non key attribute

Tags: sql-server, foreign-keys, relationship, data-modeling

I wish to define a relationship between a parent->child table.

The field in the parent table is a non key attribute(relation_field_A). I would like to define a relationship between the parent table and the child table via the relation_field_A field. I want to ensure that a value in Table_B.relation_field_A exists in the Table_A.relation_field_A.

What I want is a non-identifying relationship between the parent and child table. Is this possible?

```
Table_A
------
Key_A - PK
field1
feild2
relation_field_A

Table_B
-------
Key_B  - PK
field1
field2
relation_field_A
```

Comment: I understand you want to put a foreign key from tableB to tableA, correct? Column `relation-field-A` in table A must have at least an unique index if you want to do this

Answer (score 1):

If you want to make a foreign key from Table_B to Table_A, then the column in Table_A must have at least an unique index

```
create unique nonclustered index UX_TableA on table_A (relation_field_A)
```

See [this example](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2019&fiddle=58bb3b246abb59e524843dc73d8ce41b)

Without this, you would allow a `child` to have a link to more than one parent, which is not allowed. In a master-child relationship a parent can have 0, 1 or many childs, and a child can have only one parent.

If that is not what you want than you maybe are after a `many to many` relation ship ?
For that you need a third table which links both together.
There are many examples on google about many-to-many relationships

And if you really just want to ensure that the relation-field-a in Table_B exists in Table_A without an unique index than you cannot achieve this with a foreign key, you could write a trigger on both tables to try to ensure this.
But honestly, it seems like a design flaw has been made somewhere here.